# How can I use different params in protractor multiplecapabilities test?

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, undefined

I'm trying to run multiplecapabilities tests and each browser uses a different login, but I'm getting this error:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

SPEC FILE:

```
loginPage.pegarInput('username',browser.params[0].username),
loginPage.pegarInput('password',browser.params[0].password)`
```

CONFIG.JS FILE:

```
multiCapabilities: [{

    browserName: 'chrome',
      params: {
        username:'username',
        password:'password'
      },
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu","--no-sandbox"]
     }
    },

    {
      browserName: 'safari',
        params: {
          username:'username',
          password:'password'
        }
      }],
```

Comment: params is an object not an array so remove the `[0]`

Comment: If i do that, then i get this error
 - Failed: each key must be a number of string; got undefined

Answer (score 0):

I would probably take this approach but there are different ways to achieve what you want.
This approach has a single params object in the config with all the credentials. Then in the onPrepare it figures out which browser is running (a separate onPrepare runs for each capability) and saves that browserName as a global variable. To use the login credentials you use square bracket notation to access the specific browser name using the new global variable.

```
exports.config = {
    params: {
        chrome: {
           username: 'chromeUsername',
           password: 'chromePassword'
        },
        firefox: {
           username: 'firefoxUsername',
           password: 'firefoxPassword'
        }
    },
    multiCapabilities:{
      ...
    },
    onPrepare: async () => {
       const capabilities = await browser.getCapabilities();
       global.currentBrowser = capabilities.map_.get('browserName');

    }
    ...
}
```

**Usage**

```
loginPage.pegarInput('username',browser.params[currentBrowser].username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `browser.getProcessedConfig()` as below:

```
return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
  // config.capabilities is the CURRENT capability being run, if
  // you are using multiCapabilities.
  console.log('Executing capability', config.capabilities);
  loginPage.pegarInput('username', config.params.username)
});

// when use await/async
config = await browser.getProcessedConfig()
loginPage.pegarInput('username', config.params.username)
```